# C# Заполнить массив 10% - единицы, 40% - двойки, 50% тройки

Tags: c#

Язык С#, пойму любой другой Си-видный язык. 
Не понимаю как это реализовать, помогите пожалуйста, у кого есть идеи? 
Имеется массив, размерностью N, заполненный следующим образом : 1 : 10%, 2 : 40%, 3 : 50%, 
Пример : 1222233333. Реализовать для любого N.

Comment: Здесь не отвечают на вопросы типа "не понимаю как...". Вы должны были попытаться что-то сделать и потом если не получилось, показать что именно не получилось. Не получилось взять 10% от числа N? Не получилось создать нужный цикл и заполнить с его помощью массив одинаковыми числами?

Comment: Вариантов множество. Решение в лоб - Заполнить весь массив тройками. Следом полмассива с начала двойками, следом десятую с начала единицами.

Comment: Тут нужно подумать чисто математически

Comment: *Имеется массив, размерностью N ... Пример : 1222233333.* Размерность массива - это немного не то, о чём Вы думаете. *Реализовать для любого N* И Вы неспособны, имея общее количество и процент каждого значения, посчитать, сколько каждого значения в штуках, что ли?

Comment: Zealint, не знал этих правил, моя ошибка, больше не повторится